# Prolog List Arguments Error

Tags: prolog

I have a sum function described below:

```
list_sum([], 0).
list_sum([Head | Tail], TotalSum) :-
   list_sum(Tail, Sum1),
   TotalSum is Head + Sum1.
```

If I call this function like this for example:

```
list_sum([1,2,3], Sum).
```

The output is:

```
Sum = 6.
```

However if I decide to input the list like this:

```
L = [1,2,3].
list_sum(L, Sum).
```

The output is:

```
L = [],
Sum = 0
ERROR: is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

I've searched for a while and have done some tracing but I have no idea what's going on, probably mainly because I'm a beginner with Prolog. Anyways, can someone give me a light on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should use the comma `,/2` to express a conjunction: `L = [1,2,3], list_sum(L, Sum).`.

Comment: Your interrogation was actually `list_sum(L, Sum)` (with `L` being a free variable) which can be satisfied using the first rule, unifying `L` with `[]` and `Sum` with `0`. Then, when trying to *use* the second rule, the variable `Head` is uninstantiated and that produces an error when trying to satisfy `TotalSum is Head + 0`.

Comment: @TudorBerariu Your comment should be an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Conjunctions in Prolog**

If you want to satisfy a goal that represents a conjunction of two subgoals (no matter if they share variables or not) you must use `,/2`. In conclusion, your interrogation should be

`?- L = [1, 2, 3], list_sum(L, Sum).
L = [1, 2, 3],
Sum = 6.`

**Explaining Prolog's answer**

Your interrogation was actually `list_sum(L, Sum)` with both `L` and `Sum` being uninstantiated.

The goal is first satisfied by unifying `L` with `[]` and `Sum` with 0 (using the first rule).

If you hit <kbd>;</kbd> or <kbd>SPACE</kbd>, Prolog tries to resatisfy the goal using the second rule. Your new goal stack is `list_sum(Tail, Sum1), TotalSum is Head + Sum1`, where both `Head` and `Tail` are free variables. Again, the first goal is proved unifying `Tail` with `[]` and `Sum1` with 0, leaving `TotalSum is Head + 0` on the stack. Trying to satisfy this last goal leads to an error as `is/2` needs a right hand expression that can be evaluated (it cannot contain uninstantiated variables).

```
?- sum_list(L, Sum).
L = [],
Sum = 0 ;
ERROR: is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

Answer (score 0):

You used a dot (`.`) instead of a comma (`,`). This implies that `L` is uninstantiated in the call to `list_sum`.

---

On a sidenote your implementation of `list_sum` is not efficient. In Prolog it is custom to use tail recursion:

```
list_sum(L,R) :-
    list_sum(L,0,R).

list_sum([],R,R).
list_sum([H|T],X,R) :-
    Y is X+H,
    list_sum(T,Y,R).
```

The difference is that when you call `list_sum` using your own method, you will call the predicate recursively building up a stack. When the end of the list is reached, the stack is reduced, but this takes a long time.

Using tail recursion, no stack is generated since the program can *overwrite* its last stack frame. You only store one register (`X`) that is updated. When you reach the end of the list, the result is returned instantly. This will yield a speedup between 33% and 50% (given the list is sufficiently large of course, for small lists, the results are unpredictable).